# syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

while i try to compile magento 2, the compilation is getting paused at (1/7) stage and an error is getting logged in error log file.
please find the error details below.

Magento version 2.1.7
PHP Version 5.6.35

Error details:
[04-Dec-2018 07:15:06 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_USE) in /app/code/Magebuzz/Testimonial/Helper/Data.php on line 1

Comment: please provide the first couple of line of the mentioned class

Comment: <?php

/**

 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 www.magebuzz.com

 */

namespace Magebuzz\Testimonial\Helper;



use Magebuzz\Testimonial\Model\TestimonialFactory;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/UPG8HwNRrdDF

Comment: Please add a slash `\\ before every **`use`** statement.